# How to get indexpath inside scrollviewdidScroll method of collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have collection view , and I would like to get current visible's(most visible cell) index path in scrollViewDidScroll method.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618020-indexpathsforvisibleitems ? For the "most visible cell", that's up to you, you need to define what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you **exact visible index cell in CollectionView**.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let selectedCell = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x/self.fieldImageCollView.frame.width)
        self.pageControl.currentPage = selectedCell
    }
```

Comment: What is `fieldImageCollView`? That sounds like a view from a specific app. You should generalize that part of your answer.

Comment: That is CollectionView object.Eg: let fieldImageCollView = UIColleitonview();

Comment: Thank you @Kudos,
if we want to change color of that only visible cell, how can I do that? (Sorry for  silly question, actually I'm beginner)

Comment: Use : let cell =  collectionview.cellForItem(at: Indexpath);  cell.bacgroundcolor = UIcolor.red;

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct and upvote me. Thanks